# SQL - Removing Hold Dates

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Users will be putting items on hold and the hold dates are recorded in [HoldDate] field. I have a stored procedure

```
UPDATE [dbo].[EmailRequest]
    SET [HoldDate] = NULL, [Status] = 'OffHold'
    WHERE [HoldDate] < GETDATE();
```

Which is executed by a vb.net program and it is set up to run every 5 minutes with task scheduler. It fails during the busy hours and wondering is there any other efficient way of doing this. Thanks.

Comment: Have you try SQL Server Agent Taks ?  https://technet.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms189089%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Comment: Perhaps filtering on the current status value? `where [Status] = 'OnHold'`

Comment: You probably have an index on HoldDate, right? That means with each row updated, the index is invalidated and the query started over... causing huge performance issues.  Try SELECTING the rows you want to update into a temp table, add an index, then do the update by joining on the primary key, not the date, and you should see a dramatic improvement.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention, it is an express edition. However, will be migrating to SQL server 2012 and will look into SQL server agent. I will try the status='OnHold' immediately. will look into pmbAustin's solution. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, you run this query every five minutes?

```
UPDATE [dbo].[EmailRequest]
    SET [HoldDate] = NULL, [Status] = 'OffHold'
    WHERE [HoldDate] < GETDATE();
```

I might think that this would be faster:

```
alter table EmailRequest add new_HoldDate as (case when HoldDate > GETDATE() then HoldDate);
alter table EmailRequest add new_Status as (case when HoldDate > GETDATE() then Status else 'OffHold');
```

This does not require an update job.  Instead, it creates new *computed* columns whose values are re-calculated when the data is accessed.  You can even put an index on them, if you like.